# How to put things in divs with true border

Tags: css, positioning

I have a div but i dont know how to set the css position attributes.  I would like the div (nav) to be placed in the middle of the page.  Then i would like to place content in the div so that the border comes around the content.  Currently, the div border doesnt border anything and the content that it should border appears below the div.

HTML:

```
         <div id='nav'>
<a id='ask' class='button' unselectable='on' style='left: 20px;' href='#'>one</a>
<a id='unanswered' class='button' unselectable='on' style='left: 120px;' href='#'>two</a>
<a id='unanswered' class='button' unselectable='on' style='left: 220px;' href='#'>three</a>
<a id='unanswered' class='button' unselectable='on' style='left: 320px;' href='#'>four</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
border: 1px solid orange;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#nav{
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid gray;
width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.button` is set to `position:absolute`, the container div (`.nav`) isn't counting their height into its own.

Add a clearing `div` after the links:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

This should do the trick.

Also, you don't really need to have your `a` elements set to `position:absolute`—here's my solution:

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right:80px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/k2cQD/).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Purmou's solution is to specifically set the `#nav`'s div height in the css:

```
#nav
{
     position: relative;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     width: 700px;
     height: 120px;
}
```

Like shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cBgZK/1/).